# Confusion about reopen vote with no actual edits shown

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

I sometimes see a reopen vote in the queue that looks something like this:

[image]

Here I see that the question has been edited, which is why I assume it is now in the reopen queue. But I don't see anything here that has actually changed (normally when I see edit changes, they are in green/red shading). Am I missing something?

Comment: I was also puzzled about that same question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do see a couple of (minor) edits in the history: https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/625237/revisions . But you're right that those edits do not show up in the reopen queue. I think that's because the edits were made before the question was even closed:

[image]

So it wasn't sent to the reopen queue automatically because of the edits, someone just disagreed that it was a duplicate and voted to reopen. I presume the reopen queue doesn't show the edits because the sequence of events suggests that the edits are unrelated to the reopen vote.

Comment: That makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: It would, of course, be enormously helpful if people voting to reopen left a comment saying why they disagree with the original decision. Some do but many do not.